# Period in a wrong position when Mathjax is viewed on iPhone

Tags: bug, mathjax, mobile-web

Consider [Explicit upper bound on the number of irreflexive binary relations on {1,…,𝑛} up to isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515035/explicit-upper-bound-on-the-number-of-irreflexive-binary-relations-on-1-u)

In the last sentence, after the last aSb, I see a period when viewed on the standard browser of an iPhone SE (but not in Firefox on Linux):

[image: period right after aSb]

According to the source code, there should be no period there. Bug? Could I ask the mods to ask the SE developers to fix this?

EDIT: It turns out that this is the period terminating the sentence. For whatever reason, it is rendered misplaced.  If you remove the period terminating the sentence, the problem disappears.

Comment: edited 5 minutes prior to this question by you.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Right. I tried to get rid of the phantom period before posting here, but failed.

Comment: line wrapping on mobile possibly. single dollar signs may wrap on mobile so it should be all on one line ending in the prriod but it isn't always.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Possibly. Could I ask the mods to ask the SE developers to fix this?

Comment: developers are probably too lazy or not site specific.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Let them speak for themselves and let us hope for the best.

Comment: Probably some of the tags ([meta-tag:mobile-web]), ([meta-tag:ios-app]) should be added - depending on where this problem manifests.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Done. The problem appears in the standard iPhone Web browser.

Comment: This bug report on [meta.se] seems somewhat similar: [Strange MathJax line break behavior in mobile browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253036). (It also has a MathJax formula broken into two lines and the text seems to follow the first line.) It is from 2015, which does not sound too optimistic.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Let's hope that as you linked this bug report there, the chances increased. (I have no reputation there on meta, so, I cannot upvote there, though I'd like to.)

Comment: The period will appear property if you enclose it within the dollars.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Wow, that’s a kludge. Semantically, a period terminates a sentence, not a formula. Anyway, good to know, thanks !!!

Answer (score 3):

Testing: Does the phantom period appear if I simplify it to this? $\forall\,a,b\in\pi_1(S)\cup \pi_2(S)\colon aSb\Leftrightarrow f(a) S' f(b)$.

*Yes*.  In this screen grab, see the period after $aSb$, but the period after $f(a) S' f(b)$ is missing.

[image: aSb]

Comment: It still appears on an iPhone and still does not appear on a Firefox in Linux.

Comment: I see an end period in chrome 79.0.3945.79 on an android device.

Comment: Same thing with Safari on my iPhone SE